# Using Dreampie with Revit

Tags: python, revit, revitpythonshell

I'm new to using python on Autodesk Revit. My favorite prompt for using python is a little app called Dreampie. It works with python and ironPython.
http://www.dreampie.org/

I was wondering if there is a way to connect this application to Revit instead of the RevitPythonShell (RPS window is modal and does not have as many features as dreampie)...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think it can't be done. Different construction - DreamPie is standalone program and RevitPythonShell seems to be plugin (embbed element) with access to Revit.

But `RevitPythonShell` is Open Source and you can make modifiactions in it.

Comment: As far as I know about programming if a simple plugin can get the Revit handler from revit and then lunch Dreampie it would be great... I'm not sure though. Thanks for response.

Comment: I think, you can run `Dreampie` on your own and you get the same result as lunching it from plugin.

Comment: I tried that. Even loaded the Dlls that 'RevitPythonShell', uses. But don't know how to connect it to the running instance of application. Don't know much about. NET

Comment: And `Dreampie` doesn't know it too. It has no build-in functions to do that. I use Dreampie but I don't use Revit so I can be wrong.

Comment: Well `dreampie` is only a shell for a shell. I'm using it with IronPython 2.7 but don't know much about. NET and can't figure out how to find the instance of Revit through the .net platform.